# Deploying Jenkins under openEmbedded environment using bitbakes

Tags: c++, jenkins, continuous-integration, openembedded, bitbake

Is there a user guide or standard practices which helps to deploy Jenkins under openEmbedded environment?

I could get the jenkins service running, it clones the repo from mercurial SCM on the buildserver using SSH credentials. The buildserver is a remote machine and till date we used to trigger manual builds using "buildmaster" account on Linux distro(Fedora core 16). Under buildmaster, we used to modify the bitbake recipes and execute bitbake commands to build the target image(standard ipk-image).

Specifically, I'm trying to figure out the right approach in making the openEmbedded environment visible to jenkins.

My plan is to

1) Create set of OE directories under jenkins-home(/var/log/jenkins) which symbolically points to buildmaster bitbake directory structure.

2) Set the environment variables in user jenkins.

3) provide user "jenkins" all privileges to execute the scripts located in the "buildmaster" account.

Am I thinking in the right direction? Also, pls advise on any suitable jenkins-plugin(if any) which might help in setting up Jenkins while handling the above described complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've extensively used yocto (based on OE) and jenkins. It works beautifully together with very little in the way of setup or problems.

We use the 'gerrit repo' tool to stitch together our git repositories, check them out, then run bitbake to build our recipes. It's all very straightforward to do.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Jenkins has become a rockstar in our project. As you said, it is all straightforward :)

Answer (score 5):

Yocto project uses [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/), which is similar to Jenkins.
Take a look at [*yocto-autobuilder*](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/yocto-autobuilder/) project.

It's meant to be easy to setup on Linux:

```csh
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/yocto-autobuilder
cd yocto-autobuilder
. ./yocto-setup-autobuilder
yocto-start-autobuilder both
```

Very [details documentaion](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/yocto-autobuilder/plain/README) had also been provided.

You might also be able to find something based around Jenkins in some of the numerous git repositories out there, however *yocto-autobuilder* is probably the most recent and well-maintained.

Comment: Had heard about buildbot before but hadn't given a serious thought so far. Picked Jenkins just because of its popularity as open source CIS. Thank you for pointing towards buildbot, will try to evaluate it for my purposes.

Comment: I haven't used my self yet, but intending to in the near future.